# How do I remove all Files and Folders from a Wine installation [Battle.net]

Tags: wine, uninstall, cleanup

I installed Battle.net using Wine, the Icon for Battle.net appeared in the Ubuntu Applications Menu.
I ran the application, however the GUI interface looked corrupted and incompatible. I used the Wine GUI to remove the application via the below method.

Alt+F2 --then type--> *Wine Uninstaller* in the enter a command box or alternatively

Open Terminal -- then type--> `wine uninstaller`

[wine_uninstaller_gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxzxu.png)

There after remove the application.

The application has since been removed from the Wine GUI and the Ubuntu application menu but the residual files still remain in the c: drive and other areas of the system.

I used the following command to locate them.

Open Terminal -- then type--> `locate -i battle*`

Within the below image is what remains

[battle_net_residual_files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOCCx.png)

What is the best approach in removing all these files
as in future I will utilise the same or similar method.

Side Information:
*Description:   Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan*

Answer (score 0):

after extensive reading, the ideal solution was presented in the below link.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-delete-and-remove-files-on-ubuntu-linux/

1. Open Terminal -- then type--> `locate -i battle*` - this will give the file paths
2. Within Terminal --type--> `rm -rf -i` /path/... either directory or file name

Comment: If you're manually typing the filenames you shouldn't need `-i` as that is meant to ask for confirmation. It would be possible to use xargs to pass the list from locate to `rm -i` for confirmation or `xargs -p rm` to have xargs confirm before executing the `rm {file}` command each time. This would be best with `locate -0` or `find -print0` to handle spaces or newlines in names on systems that may have that problem, along with `xargs -0` to split on the NUL character (\0) so it's splitting the input properly for rm.